# Non-invasive DC current test

Tags: current-measurement, repair, troubleshooting

I've been trying to restore an old HP400D Vacuum Tube Voltage Meter. Section 5-20(f) in the [manual](http://www.mcmlv.org/Archive/TestEquipment/HP400.pdf) says:

> Measure the direct current in the lead from V7 (pin 1) which must be less than 60mA... Excessive current indicates a short or partial short in the circuits of the voltmeter amplifier section. *A clip-on type milliammeter should be used for this measurement.*

Presumably, the manual is saying to use something like the [HP Model 428B](http://www.hparchive.com/Manuals/HP-428B-Manual.pdf). Unfortunately, I don't have one. Therefore, I am wondering if there is another way to measure the DC current without having to cut the wire. Since I'm only testing for a short (or near-short), and the expected current is very small, I don't think need an extremely accurate measurement. Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to google "Hall effect sensor". But what types are available and which ones would work with whatever meter you do have, I don't know (and digging in to the specifics would make this a shopping question, off topic for this site).

Comment: The "Theory of Operation" section of the manual you linked might also give you some ideas if you want to DIY.